# Multi emails and phone database query MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to store contacts in MySQL where one person can have many emails and phone numbers, I have created below diagram.

**Please help me with the best query to get all emails and phones contacts of person.**

However, if this schema is not good please advise me of a better schema.

I am using below query which is giving me emails:

```
SELECT person.id, first_name, last_name, emails.email
  FROM `person_has_emails`
LEFT JOIN person ON person.id = person_has_emails.person_id
LEFT JOIN emails ON person_has_emails.emails_id = emails.id
  LIMIT 0 , 30
```

However, I want first_name, last_name, email, phone_number returned from a single query. Please advise.

[image: MySQL simple database schema]

Comment: "Please help me with the best query to get all emails and phones contacts of person" what is your actual query ?

Comment: I want first_name, last_name, email, phone_number these column from a single query.

Comment: Ok what code do you have so far? This is a fairly large and entire "stage" of production, which we cannot do for you. Can help with certain parts of your code you're stuck with, however.

Comment: @James I have updated question with my Query

Comment: Few thoughts on schema: I don't think you would require an extra table to store email and phone. You could store phone in person_has_phone itself. Person to phone is itself many relation and creating an extra table would just add a complexity/overhead. So, instead of phone_id in person_has_phone store the phone itself. Same goes for email. Just a thought!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be:

```
SELECT A.first_name, A.last_name, C.email, E.phone FROM person A
LEFT JOIN person_has_emails B on B.person_id = A.id
LEFT JOIN emails C ON B.emails_id = C.id
LEFT JOIN person_has_phone D ON D.person_id = A.id
LEFT JOIN phone E ON D.phone_id = E.id
```

But this will produce overhead. Emails will be paired with phone numbers, so if you have a person with 3 emails and 2 phone numbers you will have 6 rows in total for that same person.

Now, moving on to schema - you should remove the person_has emails and person_has_phone tables and link emails and phones directly to person. That is because one email or phone can not belong to multiple people. Or can it?

Comment: Thanks for explanation, so i need to add a FK person_id in emails and phone table. and sure one email and phone_number can belong with one person